# VBA: If changed cell is in a certain column execute subroutine

Tags: vba, intersect

I am trying to create a subroutine that runs when any cell in column 13 is changed. I've read a number of stack overflow questions already, but have not found my answer. here are some I've read:

[Not activated by a change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773730/vba-excel-if-cell-in-one-column-contains-email-address-and-cell-in-another-col)

[Uses intersect. Doesn't address my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383042/excel-vba-intersect)

[Might work but I'm not very good with events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716232/change-value-of-cell-in-same-row-with-google-script-if-column-has-certain-value)

I tried to make it work using the intersect fuction

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect (Target, Activesheet.Columns(13)) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Help Help"
EndIf

End Sub
```

This works when I change values but if left alone for a while it will come up with "Run-time error '1004': Method 'intersect of object '_Global' failed". Any ideas welcome. if there is a simpler way to acheive this, I'd love to know. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

to handle ALL worksheet, place this in ThisWorkbook code pane

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Columns(13)) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Help Help"
End If

End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 13 Then
    MsgBox "Help Help"
End If

End Sub
```

Otherwise place the following in the code pane of the Sheet(s) you want to "handle" only

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 13 Then
    MsgBox "Help Help"
End If

End Sub
```